# Recovering data from a zpool with a missing device

Tags: linux, debian, zfs, data-recovery, zfsonlinux

I have a zpool consisting of two mirrored drives, storing all my personal data. I wanted to add another mirror drive, since the other drives have been in use for several years now. Instead, I managed to cripple the pool and cannot import it any longer.

This was the original layout of the pool (called "vault") before I did anything:

```
vault
  mirror-0
    sdd
    sdh
```

I tried to add another drive by issuing `zpool add vault /dev/sdc`, and got a warning from zpool (something about expecting a vdev, but scd being a disk). I ignored the warning, and forced the operation with `-f` (yes, that was pretty stupid ... )

I ended up with the following pool configuration:

```
vault
  mirror-0
    sdd
    sdh
  sdc
```

Noticing that sdc was not part of the mirror, I tried to remove it from the pool again and realized that this is not possible. I ignored the extra drive and rebooted, and assumed that my data is already safe inside the mirror-0 and decided to use repurpose sdc and use another drive instead, overwriting the first 100MB of sdc with zeros: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=1MB count=100` (yes, I am particularly stupid today ... )

Now when I try to import my zpool, I get the following error:

```
root@atlas:~# zpool import                                                                                                                         
   pool: vault                                                                                                                                     
     id: 3553551207657826252                                                                                                                       
  state: UNAVAIL                                                                                                                                   
 status: One or more devices are missing from the system.                                                                                          
 action: The pool cannot be imported. Attach the missing                                                                                           
        devices and try again.                                                                                                                     
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-6X                                                                                                      
 config:                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                   
        vault        UNAVAIL  missing device                                                                                                       
          mirror-0   ONLINE                                                                                                                        
            sdd      ONLINE                                                                                                                        
            sdh      ONLINE                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                   
        Additional devices are known to be part of this pool, though their                                                                         
        exact configuration cannot be determined.
```

The data in the mirror on these drives is extremely important to me, and I really hope there is a way of restoring the data from the "partial" pool. Since I had rebooted a few minutes after the bogus `add` operation, I am assuming that the metadata for the file system was wiped, and that there is a way to access the raw data somehow. But I have no clue where to start.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to recover parts of the data by upgrading debian to bullseye (in order to have access to a more recent version of zdb) and [importing the zpool with missing vdevs](https://www.delphix.com/blog/openzfs-pool-import-recovery):

```
echo 1 >> /sys/module/zfs/parameters/zfs_max_missing_tvds
zpool import -o readonly=on vault
```

Some of the filesystems on the zpool were corrupt, though. I have copied the intact data onto a new zpool, and probed earlier [txg](https://www.delphix.com/blog/delphix-engineering/zfs-fundamentals-transaction-groups) values to find one that did not throw any errors:

```
zdb -e vault -ul | grep ' txg' | sed 's/.*= //' | sort | head
zdb -deG -o zfs_max_missing_tvds=1 -T 5102203 vault  # <- errors
zdb -deG -o zfs_max_missing_tvds=1 -T 5102202 vault  # <- errors
zdb -deG -o zfs_max_missing_tvds=1 -T 5102201 vault  # <- worked!
```

I was then able to import the zpool at the intact transaction group id:

```
zpool import -o readonly=on -T 5102201 vault
```

This command took about 15 hours for my 2x4TB mirror, but I could access all my files again. The data has since been copied onto a new zpool that I won't ever touch in a sleep-deprived state again.